# TLS client not failing the handshake even when SNI is not matching with subject received in server-certificate

Tags: openssl, x509certificate, tls1.2

I'm trying to understand the TLS handshake. In the client-hello am sending the SNI-extention's hostname set to say "server1". But the TLS server is sending a server-certificate with the subject/common-name/FQDN as "random-server". I'm expecting that the TLS client should fail the certificate validation and should teardown the connection. But, I see the connection is not teared-down and the certificate validation also passes.

Am using "openssl s_server" as TLS server and "openssl s_client" as TLS client. Below are the commands:-

```
openssl s_server -key serverkey.pem -cert servercert.pem -accept 4433 -msg -debug -state
openssl s_client -servername tls-server -connect localhost:4433 -state -debug -msg -tlsextdebug -CAfile cacert.pem
```

Important logs on server side :-

```
TLS client extension "server name" (id=0), len=18
0000 - 00 10 00 00 0d 72 61 6e-64 6f 6d 2d 73 65 72 76   .....random-serv
0010 - 65 72

SSL_accept:SSLv3 write server hello A
>>> TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 0540], Certificate
...
...
0120 - 30 11 06 03 55 04 03 0c-0a 74 6c 73 2d 73 65 72   0...U....tls-ser
0130 - 76 65 72 30 82 01 22 30-0d 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7   ver0.."0...*.H..
```

Important logs on Client side :-

```
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=IN/ST=KA/L=Bangalore/O=xxx/CN=tls-server

    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

Comment: (0) this is not about programming or development (1) `s_client` (and other commandline operations) doesn't check hostname in cert unless you specify `-verify_{hostname,ip,name,email}` -- see the man page for `verify` (2) most SSL/TLS certs for over a decade use SubjectAlternativeName (SAN) for the hostname(s) and NOT CommonName (3) `s_client` is a test tool and does not abort the connection even for cert errors it does detect (like untrusted CA or expired) without `-verify_return_error`

Comment: even with verify argument s_client doesn't seem to verify the hostname:-
"openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:4433 -CAfile cacert.pem -servername wrongname -verify 2"

Comment: **I didn't say `-verify`**; if you look at the man page that clearly doesn't have anything to do with name checking. I said `-verify_hostname` or `-verify_ip` or `-verify_email` (but I was in error about `-verify_name`, that's actually different). If you look at the man page as I suggested, the descriptions of those 3 and only those 3 clearly tell you about name checking.

Comment: I guess those options are  not supported openssl 0..98. But, anyways thanks. It helped a bit.

Comment: Yes, those options were new in 1.0.0; 0.9.x did not have that functionality. I generally assume people aren't using software obsolete for more than a decade unless stated so.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I should have mentioned it before.